# How to mock await dynamoDb.putItem(...).promise()?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to mock a call to Dynamo DB:

```
exports.handler = async (event, connection, publish) => {
    // ... stuff ...
    await dynamoDb.putItem({
        TableName: "...",
        Item: { ... }
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error :-(", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Success :-)", data);
        }
    }).promise();
    // ... stuff ...
}
```

This is the mock attempt:

```
var mock = require('mock-require');

mock('aws-sdk', {
    DynamoDB: class DynamoDB {
        putItem(obj, f) {
            console.log('putItem')
        }
    }
})
```

But I'm constantly receiving this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: dynamoDb.putItem(...).promise is not a function`

... which makes sense, but how am I working aroung it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function you have,

```js
await dynamoDb.putItem(params).promise()
```

so what you could do in your mock is return an object containing a `promise` field which is a function returning a `Promise`.

```js
mock('aws-sdk', {
    DynamoDB: class DynamoDB {
        putItem(obj, f) {
            return {
              promise: () => Promise.resolve();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and from there procceed and return if you want some mock data or not.